# error: return type is an incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, return-type

I can't understand what does it mean:

```
error: return type is an incomplete type"
```

I just want to return the struct. I had separated two audio channels and I'd like to return them using a struct using the only function.

**main.c**:

```
#include "functions.h"
...
struct LandR sepChannels_8( unsigned char *, unsigned long, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
...
int main()
{
    ...

    sepChannels_8( ptrSamples_8, n, ptrSamples_8_L, ptrSamples_8_R );

    ...
}
```

**function.h**:

```
...
struct LandR sepChannels_8( unsigned char *smp, unsigned long N, unsigned char *L, unsigned char *R )
{
    struct LandR
{
    unsigned char *L;
    unsigned char *R;
};
struct LandR LRChannels;

int i;

if ( N % 2 == 0 )
{
    L = malloc(N/2);
    R = malloc(N/2);
}
else
    if ( N % 2 == 1 )
    {
        L = malloc(N/2);
        R = malloc(N/2);
    }

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )    // separating
{
    L[2 * i + 0] = smp[2 * i + 0];
    R[2 * i + 0] = smp[2 * i + 1];
}
return LRChannels;
}
...
```

Comment: Is the struct _defined_ at the point you try to use it? Is that a typo in your sample code or are you really trying to define the return type of the function within the function itself?

Comment: Your usage of the `.c` and `.h` files is pretty much backwards - you have the prototype in `main.c` and the function body in `function.h`. But you did manage to put `main` in `main.c`.

Comment: In my case I include part of pacakge file but not coomplete package file, after correct the include file, the error is solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a type you need to declare it before.

`struct LandR` is declared locally to `sepChannels_8`.

Move the declaration into global scope, if you want to expose it as returned type of a function.

---

Also: Per convention prototypes and constants and type definitions go into `.h` files. Implementations go into `.c` files.

Comment: You want to say that I must: declare variables, functions' prototypes in `.h` and realise these functions in `.c`?

Comment: @yulian: "*You want to say that I must*" No.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the complete declaration of the struct is not present, only a forward declaration (like `struct foo;`), so the return type is incomplete - you can't do that.

Comment: Would it be good if I create `struct LandR LRChannels` in the beginning of `main.c` and then pass LRChannels to a function as argument and after all return this struct that includes 2 arrays (channels)?

Comment: @Julian Define the struct in the header instead. Include the header when/where needed.

Answer (score 1):

A little more explanation (which should be available in every good C tutorial as well):

Put everything what must be present in several places into a `.h` file. That is, mainly `extern` declarations of variables, function prototypes, typedefs, structs, enums etc.

Put the actual code of every function into a `.c` file. Let them include the needed `.h` files and only the needed ones.

Prevent multiple inclusion of header files with an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).